# Who made the decision for Gandalf's promotion from 'grey' to 'white'?

Tags: tolkiens-legendarium, the-lord-of-the-rings, gandalf

In the first book of the LoTR, after his fight with the Balrog of Moria, Gandalf the Grey changed to [Gandalf the White](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gandalf#Gandalf_the_White).

My question is, **who made the decision to 'promote' him from grey to white?** Was it [Eru](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Eru_Il%C3%BAvatar)? Or was it the [Ainu](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ainu_%28Middle-earth%29)? Or was it the [Valar](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vala_%28Middle-earth%29)?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How is Gandalf the White a "significantly more powerful figure" than Gandalf the Gray?](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/13346/how-is-gandalf-the-white-a-significantly-more-powerful-figure-than-gandalf-the)

Comment: Also, http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20242/how-does-a-wizard-change-his-colour

Answer (score 45, accepted):

After dying fighting the Balrog of Moria, Gandalf was "sent back" as Gandalf the White by Eru.

[Here is an analysis](http://tolkien.cro.net/else/gdfdie.html) of Gandalf's death and resurrection, but let me extract the relevant sentences from letter #156 (emphasis mine):

> "For in his condition it was for him a sacrifice to perish on the Bridge in defence of his companions
>
> [...]
>
> He was handing over to **the Authority that ordained the Rules**, and giving up personal hope of success.
>
> [...]
>
> Gandalf really 'died', and was changed [...] He was sent by a mere prudent plan of the angelic Valar or govenors; but **Authority had taken up this plan and enlarged it**, at the moment of its failure. 'Naked I was sent back- for a brief time, until my task is done'. Sent back by whom, and whence? **Not by the 'gods'** whose business is only with this embodied world and its time; for he passed 'out of thought and time'. Naked is alas! unclear. It was meant just literally, 'unclothed like a child' (not disincarnate), and so ready to receive the white robes of the highest.

Hopefully this shows that it wasn't the Valar who "sent Gandalf back", but a higher Authority "who ordained the Rules", and also that Gandalf was literally naked before this Authority, who gave him the "white robes of the highest".

This Authority above the Valar can be none other than Eru.

Comment: +1, also Gandalf's "*I strayed out of thought and time*" - especially "**out of time**" confirms that he had left Ea.

Comment: How did the elves of Lothlorien know to cloth him in white robes?

Comment: Maybe they asked him.

Comment: But it begs the question. Why did Gandalf  "strain out of thought and time" when his mortal body was slain? Isn't he supposed to be a Maia?

Comment: @Default_User Evidently a Maia's mortal body can die. Maiar like Gandalf are not of this world. As Tolkien explained, the decision to resurrect him as a mortal was made by Eru, and Eru also decided to promote him to Gandalf the White.

Comment: @AndresF. No but a Maia spirit is supposed to outlast its body and remain in Arda. The gift of mortality was not given to any but Men. My question is why didn't Gandalf's spirit "escape" and stay in middle earth when his body was slain like what happened with Sauron and Saruman?

Comment: @Default_User What evidence is there that Maiar are supposed to stay in Arda by default? I also don't see what role the gift of mortality is supposed to play here: after all, Hobbits, Dwarves, Orcs and Elves can be killed as well. Their spirits do not go "beyond" as Humans do, but that's besides the point. In any case, Tolkien himself told us what happened to Gandalf and who was responsible, thereby answering this particular question :)

Comment: The promotion as such seems to be that Gandalf is more powerful after the resurrection. The color part seems unrelated - the leader of the Istari was out of tradition The White, and since Saruman had turned traitor (and was now of "many colors"), someone else had to pick up the role. Gandalf would be the natural choice as the 3 others seem quite irrelevant and inactive. I always assumed this was Gandalf's own choice.

Comment: @Amarth It seems to me grey & white are both figurative and literal. He was "promoted" by Eru, and this promotion meant donning "the white robes of the highest". Gandalf didn't make this decision but, like Tolkien says, the decision was made for him by "the Authority that ordained the rules", namely Eru.